# mac OS X version 10.6.5 network connection troubleshooting/solution?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, command-line-interface, local-area-network, troubleshooting

Im connected to a small office network where where everything works fine. however once in a while or on a random occasion usually after the computer has been left on or on sleep all night there are strange connection issues.

I find I cannot connect to the network drive. Sometimes it connects but cannot read any files and other times it reads the files but cannot open them. then Im hit with two error messages.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

When I try to refresh/reconnect to the drive it gets stuck in an endless loading loop.
The only solution is to restart the whole system, once this is done, its fine again.

Having to restart a system 3 times a day is not ideal, and these errors have me intrigued however I have not been able to find a solution. I would be very grateful if someone could help me find a solution. thanks.

1. What do these errors mean?
2. A system restart fixes the issues so is there
   some way to refresh the connection
   through command line without having
   to restart the system / or a viable
   alternative?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on some of the systems where I work, and again it's related to mounting network volumes, both via SMB & AFP.  I'm not sure which is the culprit at this point, but it's starting to look like a bug in OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacErrors.h" you'll find the following line:

```
  errFSBadFSRef                 = -1401, /* FSRef parameter is bad */
```

FSRef's are "filesystem references", and when this sort of error occurs, it's usually the result of disk corruption.  I would check the drive you're connecting to, run whatever diagnostics are appropriate, etc.  It could be some sort of connection issue to the drive, but without knowing what means you're using to connect (SMB, NFS, etc) it's hard to say.

Comment: TIL, OSX comes with un-compiled header files.